# Create event subscription target ARN dropdown is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an event subscription from my RDS PostgreSQL instance to my Lambda Function. However, the target dropdown for ARN is empty as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEQaS.png). How do I make my Lambda Function appear in the dropdown? Is it a permission policy in the Lambda Function?

Comment: RDS only supports SNS as target. You can then subscribe your lambda to that SNS topic. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html